# Looking for an existing iGoogle/OpenSocial gadget comparable to iGoogle's default native RSS gadget

Tags: widget, rss, opensocial

iGoogle's standard RSS feed gadget is not OpenSocial, so it can't be embedded in other web sites. So I am hoping there is an alternative solution already available somewhere.

In [iGoogle's gadget list](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open) there are other RSS gadgets, but none of them seem as nice as the default one by Google which is native to iGoogle.

The main difference between the standard gadget and most others is the ability to expand a headline and see more of the article by clicking the arrow next to the story. Also a clean layout.

It must be a widget/gadget that is OpenSocial compatible.

(I am aware that iGoogle will be closing, that is not relevant to my needs.)

Answer (score 1):

`MyYahoo`:
Appears overall best alternative to iGoogle in terms of setup speed, "just working", and widgets for average or  novice users.
appears not to import opml, but can support rss feeds
by hand can setup the same rss feeds as igoogle or netvibes
supports upto 9 tabs. every tab has an advertisement
only supports Yahoo search
appears no wikipedia search widget
good support for display of stock portfolio quotes in widgets provided by Yahoo
several good yahoo widgets provided, e.g. tv guide, local movies
can have different theme for each tab, or all the same.
can use uploaded image for wallpaper.
can make backgrounds transparent.
can set background and text colors for all parts of a theme, separately.
has spectrum chooser for colors. cannot type in hex codes.
very user friendly interface for configuring themes.
supports user-created applications (widgets) for MyYahoo tabs.

[This is how to get started with it](http://developer.yahoo.com/myyahoo/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [**Skim.Me**](http://skim.me) as an alternative to embedding iGoogle's RSS gadget